# CrawlSpider with dynamically generated Rules and spider arguments is not scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am currently trying to create a spider which is recursively following the page I am giving it. Its purpose is to scrape the content of articles from news portals. Two things that are important for its implementation:

- I must be able to provide an argument for the spider with the portal URL,
- I want to dynamically generate a regex to the article URL based on the portal link given earlier.

The argument for the spider is needed because I want to create a spider per portal that I intend to crawl.

Regex is needed for the Rule and LinkExtractor.

The problem is that the spider after running does not work recursively and does not collect any documents. As if dynamically generated rules did not apply.

In the implementation of my spider, I used **init** to pass there a variable called portal, in which there is an URL to the portal, which I want to scrape.

In **init** I also create rules and compile them.

I use the Dragnet external library to extract the content of the articles.

```py
import scrapy
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.spiders import Rule, CrawlSpider
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from ..items import ArticleExtractorItem

import re
import tldextract
from dragnet import extract_content

class ArticleExtractorSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "article_extractor"

    def __init__(self, portal=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ArticleExtractorSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if portal:
            url_escaped = re.escape(portal)
            article_regex = r'^' + url_escaped + \
                r'([a-zA-Z0-9]+-){2,}[a-zA-Z0-9]+\/$'

            ArticleExtractorSpider.rules = (
                Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=[article_regex]),
                     callback='parse_article', follow=True),
            )

            super(ArticleExtractorSpider, self)._compile_rules()

        self.portal = portal

    def parse_article(self, response):
        article = extract_content(response.body)
        portal = tldextract.extract(response.url)[1]

        l = ItemLoader(item=ArticleExtractorItem(), response=response)
        l.add_value('portal', portal)
        l.add_value('url', response.url)
        l.add_xpath('title', './/meta[@name="twitter:title"]/@content')
        l.add_xpath('title', './/meta[@property="og:title"]/@content')
        l.add_xpath('publish_date',
                    './/meta[@property="article:published_time"]/@content')
        l.add_value('article', article)

        yield l.load_item()
```

After starting the spider, no requests were even made. Zero documents have been downloaded.

Comment: I think you're missing [start_urls](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.start_urls)

Comment: Thank you so much! It started working. :)